# Removing empty attributes on update

Tags: symfony4, php-7.3

I have an issue with FOSElasticaBundle, with emptying/removing attributes in elasticsearch.

I'm running:

friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle  v5.0.3
ruflin/elastica v6.1.1
jms/serializer-bundle v3.2.0
jms/serializer v2.3.0
symfony v4.2.7
elasticsearch v6.7.1

When I save an object via doctrine. it get's correctly serialized and are being send to elasticsearch. Each update is also working:

```
{  
   "update":{  
      "_index":"demo_companies",
      "_type":"company",
      "_id":13
   }
}
{  
   "doc":{  
      "id":13,
      "company_name":"Demo Company",
      "company_tagline":"Only the finest",
   },
   "doc_as_upsert":true
}
```

But when I clear the company_tagline in the form and save it gets emptied in the database, as expected. Now after serialization, the company_tagline is missing, due to not serializing empty string. So the bulk update looks like this:

```
{  
   "update":{  
      "_index":"demo_companies",
      "_type":"company",
      "_id":13
   }
}
{  
   "doc":{  
      "id":13,
      "company_name":"Demo Company",
   },
   "doc_as_upsert":true
}
```

When now querying elasticsearch the company_tagline is still in place:

```
{
    "took" : 0,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 14,
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "demo_companies",
                "_type" : "company",
                "_id" : "13",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "id" : 13,
                    "company_name" : "FTI Touristik GmbH",
                    "company_tagline":"Only the finest"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I assume that's because `doc_as_upsert` only updates attributes in place. So since company_tagline is missing in the request it does not get updated/removed.

Is there any way to perform a hard update of the entry instead of upserting it?